# how to write a loop function for this question?

Tags: python

im stuck for 2 hours :(
Write a function called length_of_longest_word that accepts one list variable called word_list as an argument and returns the length of the longest word in that list. Hint: initialize a variable above your loop with a statement like this: max_length = 0. Then, in the body of your loop, use the max function to compare this max_length value with the length of the current word, like this: max(max_length, length_of_current_word), and then update max_length appropriately with the new value. If you get lost, try adding some print statements inside of your loop!

answer:

```
assert length_of_longest_word(["these", "are", "diminuitive", "words"]) == 11
assert length_of_longest_word(["short", "tiny", "haha", "antidisestablishmentarianism"]) == 28
```

my own work stuck here:

max_length = 0
def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
    for item in (word_list):
        abb = max_length + len(item)
        print (abb)

```
return max(abb)
```

length_of_longest_word(["these", "are", "diminuitive", "words"])

(with typoerror pop out)

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Stack Overflow is meant to be a place where people with specific code issues can get advice. Have a look at the guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then update your post to show you've given this the ol' college try ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def length_of_longest_word(word_list):
    max_length = 0
    for word in word_list:
        max_length = max(max_length,len(word))
    return max_length

print (length_of_longest_word(["these", "are", "diminuitive", "words"]))
```